# I have a valid visa for 2 years, how to apply visa for wife and children

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, family, emirates

I have a two years multiple C Class visa and i want to take my wife and children for a holiday in UK. I will be bearing all expenses of their travel. What will be procedure to apply for the visa for them, whether my wife will be the primary applicant in this case.

Comment: Why would you expect the procedure to be any different from any other UK visa?